# CAPTCHA Weakness to Automated Attack

Tags: captcha

EDIT: This question was dumb, I misread the quote that made me ask it. Sorry.

This is more of a follow up question from schroeder's answer to another question.

schroeder said that CAPTCHAs are vulnerable to automated attack. After looking around it seems like modern CAPTCHAs are not (as far as I can find), the closest I have seen was a criminal organization having random people solve CAPTCHAs for them in exchange for access to porn or other online goods.

What attacks exist that are truly automated?

Comment: No dude... I said they **prevented** online attacks.....

Comment: Oops, lysdexia. Sorry, will close question. Actually, I can't.

Comment: I said they can be cracked by automated tools :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be modern forms of CAPTCHA that do not have automated tools yet, but a quick Google search will provide tools to crack various CAPTCHA systems with varying success rates.

In addition, not only are there sites that pay people to interpret CAPTCHAs (including Amazon's Mechanical Turk), but some warez include a CAPTCHA that must be passed in order to allow the user to access the software, but the CAPTCHA is a capture of a live crack attempt from some other source.